# NServiceBus generic message handlers not found using conventions unobtrusive mode

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, nservicebus

I am using dotnetcore2.1 app with aspnetcore 2.1.1.
Also I'm using the `Community.NServiceBus.WebHost` for hosting in that version as suggested in the documentation.

I am trying to have a clean architecture not to depend directly on NServiceBus, therefore I'm using adapters and unobtrusive mode for my commands. I am getting the following exception and immediate retries attempts.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No handlers could be found for message type: WebApi.Models.Commands.ProcessBlob
```

This is how I register NServiceBus with this custom extension

```
public static IServiceCollection AddNServiceBus(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var endpointName = configuration.GetValue<string>("NServiceBus:EndpointName");
    var connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("NServiceBus:ConnectionString");

    var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(endpointName);
    endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
    endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
    var conventions = endpointConfiguration.Conventions();
    conventions.DefiningMessagesAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains(".Commands"));

    //var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
    //transport.ConnectionString(connectionString);
    endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
    services.AddNServiceBus(endpointConfiguration);
    
    services.AddTransient<ICommandBus, CommandBusAdapter>();

    services.AddTransient<ICommandHandler<ProcessBlob>, ProcessBlobHandler>();
    
    return services;
}
```

Then at `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddNServiceBus(Configuration)
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

I've got the following adapter for sending commands

```
public class CommandBusAdapter
    : ICommandBus
{
    private readonly IMessageSession _messageSession;

    public CommandBusAdapter(IMessageSession messageSession)
    {
        _messageSession = messageSession;
    }

    public Task Send<TCommand>(TCommand command) 
        where TCommand : class
    {
        return _messageSession.SendLocal(command);
    }
}
```

and this is my generic message handler adapter that I use to handle ANY command and use a service locator to determine the specific command handler to delegate.

```
public class CommandHandlerAdapter<TCommand>
    : IHandleMessages<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : class
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CommandHandlerAdapter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public Task Handle(TCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<TCommand>);
        var commandHandler = (ICommandHandler<TCommand>)_serviceProvider.GetService(commandHandlerType);
        return commandHandler.Handle(message);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the command handler adapter is not registered (I would expect NServiceBus to detect it and register it automatically even if it's generic).
I use a convention where the command messages are any DTO under a namespace that contains `.Commands`

**Am I trying something impossible or is there any workaround that allows me to keep using this generic command handler adapter approach?**

---

**UPDATE 1**: In other words, the following handler works fine without any additional registration.

```
public class CommandHandlerAdapter
    : IHandleMessages<ProcessBlob>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<ProcessBlob> _processBlobHandler;

    public CommandHandlerAdapter(ICommandHandler<ProcessBlob> processBlobHandler)
    {
        _processBlobHandler = processBlobHandler;
    }

    public Task Handle(ProcessBlob processBlob, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        return _processBlobHandler.Handle(processBlob);
    }
}
```

But I want a way to have this command handler adapter generic, because it does the same for every command (gets the instance of the specific command handler and delegates on it to handle the message)

Comment: It seems to me you're using a generic command handler to do _exactly_ what NServiceBus already does. Why? You've mentioned you don't want to rely on NServiceBus, which is already an abstraction. You'll lose a lot of benefits that NServiceBus offers. Don't abstract away NServiceBus. That would be the same as abstracting away ASP.NET.

Comment: I disagree Dennis, but thanks for your comment. NServiceBus is not an abstraction but a specific implementation. Same as EntityFramework is not an abstraction no matter how generic its repository is.

I could swap in the future from NServiceBus to MassTransit and I don't want to break my application tests because of that. That's why I don't want to have any direct dependency on NServiceBus or anything that I don't control.

I actually keep most ASP.NET related in an infrastructure project with my thin controllers and IoCC, although the difference is substantial :) (Microsoft..)